# Android splash screen appears after phone call

Tags: android, splash-screen

In my app, I am giving the user the option to call someone using ACTION_CALL. After the call is finished, the user is brought back to the app where they left off but the splash screen appears. I do not want this splash screen to appear at this time.

This same thing happens when I open the contact list and allow the user to select a contact, upon selecting a contact the activity is returned to my app and again the splash screen appears for an infinitesimal amount of time, making it annoying.

How do I prevent the splash screen from appearing at any other time than the main activity?

All help and ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
private void openDeviceContactsForSelection() 
{
  //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 //        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//       intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));      //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    //TODO
    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;

    String cName = "";
    String cNumber = "";

    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    String displayColumnName;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14)
        displayColumnName = "display_name";
    else
        displayColumnName = Profile.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;
    String[] projection = {displayColumnName, Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        cName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(displayColumnName));
        cNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    saveNumber(cName, cNumber);
    loadList(getSelectedNumberTypeAsEnum());
}
```

Comment: Need to provide more info, paste some code, unless you want to hear an answer "Well just delete your splash screen". :)

Comment: paste some more code tell us from where you are launching your splash screen and the flow of your app

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when a call starts, your App is moved to the background.  When the app comes back the onResume() function is called.  You would need to save state when the call starts and reload it when the app starts again.  The easiest way I know to do this is with [bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Comment: When the control comes back to the background application onResume() is called not onCreate()

Comment: Thanks! A slightly easier way is to just change the call of the launching of the splash screen into my oncreate method in my main activity and this fixed my issue. Similar idea.